# Empty factor levels were dropped for columns when using MLR package

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, mlr

I have a question here, when I try to use "makeClassifTask" from MLR package to do a SVM, a warning said Empty factor levels were dropped for columns.
My codes are:

```
install.packages("mlr")
library(mlr) 
set.seed(1)
sample=sample(2,nrow(cleaned_caravan_train),replace=T)
train=cleaned_caravan_train[sample==1,]
test=cleaned_caravan_train[sample==2,]
makeClassifTask(data=train,target = "CARAVAN")
```

An example from the MLR package works very well:

```
install.packages("mlbench")
library(mlbench)
data("BostonHousing")
data("Ionosphere")
makeClassifTask(data=iris,target="Species")
```

I don't understand what the different between those.

Comment: StackOverflow has a tag for mlr, so I'm voting to move this question there.

Comment: Notice that your example is not reproducible. It might be closed upon arrival in StackOverflow if you do not add a reproducible example (I'm of the opinion your question is answerable even without the reproducible example, but keep that in mind).

Comment: The warning most likely occurs because after you splitted the data you have some factor levels that are not present in the train set but where present in the whole data set. Also you might want to make use of the mlr resampling methods instead of splitting the data manually?